# Does django default forms block fields other than those specified?

Tags: django, django-forms

```py
class CreatePost(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'create.html'
    form_class = CreateForm

    
    @transaction.atomic
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.instance.content = post_filters(form.cleaned_data['content'])
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        PostIp.objects.create(
            postip=get_client_ip(self.request),
            postid=form.instance.id
        )
        return response

createForm

   fields = ("title", "content")
```

If a malicious person specifies an id, would it be a security issue?

I read some of the code but lost interest in reading it because of its difficulty.

Comment: `but lost interest in reading it` :D :D